# Get reference to hovered object three.js react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js

I'm using `react-three-fiber` to load a scene with many smaller objects. I want all the objects in the scene to be hoverable. I also want reference to the hoverd objects so I do things like changing their material etc. Here's my code:

```
const Scene = (props) => {
  const group = useRef();
  const { nodes, materials } = useGLTF("/scene1.glb");
  const [hovered, setHover] = useState(false);

  return (
    <group ref={group} {...props} dispose={null}>
      <mesh
        castShadow
        receiveShadow
        geometry={nodes.Floor.geometry}
        material={materials.floor_mat}
        position={[-2.27, -2.87, 13.96]}
      />
      <mesh
        castShadow
        receiveShadow
        geometry={nodes.Walls.geometry}
        material={materials.wall_mat}
        position={[-8.95, 14.68, -25.15]}
      />
</group> );
}
```

I know there are events like `onPointerEnter` and `onPointerLeave` but how do I get reference to the object which is being hovered so I can do things to that object?

Answer (score 1):

To "hover" your pointer over the objects you need to use [Raycaster](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Raycaster).
Remember to add actual scene's children as a argument of a Raycaster function, other way you won't be able to get the intersection.

From experience, I suggest you to put the raycaster function into the pointerOnMove event to gather the intersections.

This function returns an array of intersected objects, to get the actual one that you have hovered over, pick the first element from the array.